# I have two matrices, and I need find an algebraic formulation between them.

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

Consider two hypothetical matrices A and B. These matrices are defined as follow:

$$
A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & a & b & c\\
0 & 0 & 0 & d \\
0 & 0 & 0 & e \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right) 
$$

$$
B = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1-(1-b)(1-c) & 1-(1-a)(1-c) & 1-(1-a)(1-b)\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right) 
$$

My question: Is it possible to find an algebraic formula in which matrix B can be calculated (or achieved) from matrix A?

Thank you.

Comment: When you say "an algebraic formula," do you mean a polynomial. In other words, are you asking if there is a polynomial $p$ such that $p(A) = B$?

Comment: Write down $x+yA+zA^2+tA^3=B$ and see you can solve the resulting equations for $x,y,z,t$. (By Cayley Hamilton you don't need to go beyond third powers.)

Comment: Yes, I mean polynomial.

Comment: I checked and it turns out the answer is no.